# HTML Синтаксис в Angular 2. Sublime Text 3

Tags: html, angular2, sublime-text, typescript

Как настроить подсветку синтаксиса `HTML` кода в коде на `TypeScript` в `Sublime Text`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Некрасиво это - темплейт в компоненту пихать... Когда есть `templateUrl`...

Answer (score 1):

Есть плагин https://github.com/princemaple/ngx-html-syntax
В списке плагинов Sublime Text он называется `Angular2 HTML Syntax`, после установки, в списке поддерживаемых синтаксисов, необходимо выбрать `Ngx HTML`.